# Bitbucket in jenkins not working

Tags: git, maven, tomcat, jenkins, bitbucket

im trying to set up my tomcat project which is in git with bitbucket.

I have a remote server where i installed tomcat and jenkins.

I configure java sdk and maven.

I use bitbicket url as some suggested in many posts

```
https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/project.git
```

But whe it builds it throws this:

```
    Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/jobs/PROJECT/workspace
```

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url https://USER:mypass@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   git fetch --tags --progress https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1282)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

```
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1591)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1379)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:324)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:733)
... 11 more
```

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE

Please Help!

Comment: HTTP 401 means "Unauthorized" - are you sure that you used the correct password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally make it work creating file .netrc in root folder.

I used this link [TUTORIAL](http://dustint.com/post/299/hudson-jenkins-and-git-http-authentication)

And then just used simple bitbucket url in jenkins

https://bitbucket.org/user/project.git

I was using CentOs